# Eclipse integrate with qt

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

i download qt and eclipse with c++ cdt , i see that qt come with qt ide (qt creator) , to develop qt appliation and that fine , but i want to do this wit eclipse , i mean use c++ code with qt inside eclipse . is there any ? because i am trying to use qt to design my user interface only  and using  other code from other libraries to do other things .

i try to include header files (usr/include/qt4) , but i still have a problem when i compile the program such us ( can't find qgui.h ) any help the integrate qt with eclipse like netbeans .

edit :

here is my output

```
13:48:48 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -o test src/test.o -lQtCore 
src/test.o: In function `main':
/media/sda2/workspaceeclipse/test/Debug/../src/test.cpp:6: undefined reference to `QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)'
/media/sda2/workspaceeclipse/test/Debug/../src/test.cpp:8: undefined reference to `QPushButton::QPushButton(QString const&, QWidget*)'
/media/sda2/workspaceeclipse/test/Debug/../src/test.cpp:12: undefined reference to `QApplication::exec()'
/media/sda2/workspaceeclipse/test/Debug/../src/test.cpp:12: undefined reference to `QPushButton::~QPushButton()'
/media/sda2/workspaceeclipse/test/Debug/../src/test.cpp:12: undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
/media/sda2/workspaceeclipse/test/Debug/../src/test.cpp:8: undefined reference to `QPushButton::~QPushButton()'
/media/sda2/workspaceeclipse/test/Debug/../src/test.cpp:12: undefined reference to `QPushButton::~QPushButton()'
/media/sda2/workspaceeclipse/test/Debug/../src/test.cpp:12: undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
src/test.o: In function `QWidget::resize(int, int)':
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qwidget.h:996: undefined reference to `QWidget::resize(QSize const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

13:48:49 Build Finished (took 1s.609ms)
```

Comment: @cmannett85: I do not think so - you can get Eclipse running as Qt IDE very well without the QT eclipse plugin. It requires some setup effort, and I think this is where the OP is stuck.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't think there was a native Eclipse equivalent for Designer or Linguist.

Comment: @cmannett85 True - but you can assign the corresponding file types to the external applications, so that you can launch them from the project tree

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had to adjust the following settings in "Project Properties => C/C++ General => Paths and Symbols":

On the "Includes" tab, for the GNU C++ language, add the following include paths:

- /usr/include/qt4
- /usr/include/qt4/QtCore
- /usr/include/qt4/QtGui

On the "Symbols" tab, for the GNU C++ language, define the following symbols with a value of "1" (might be different for you, but at least the QT_CC_GNU, QT_CORE_LIB and QT_GUI_LIB are necessary):

- QT_CC_GNU
- QT_CORE_LIB
- QT_GUI_LIB
- QT_NO_DEBUG
- QT_SHARED
- QT_TESTLIB_LIB
- QT_WEBKIT

With these settings, the source indexer works well. Other than that, Eclipse is simply calling "make" for the build.

Comment: thanks for reply , but i get this make: *** [sdg] Error 1 and undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()' and undefined reference to `QApplication::exec()' and the last error is undefined reference to `QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)'

Comment: Are you using qmake or are you using Eclipses internal build system? Which toolchain are you using?

Comment: i am using internal builder , and i have no error now except when i run it i get "launch failed , Binary not found"

Comment: You can set the executable to launch in your "Run configuration" (in the "Run configurations" dialog, choose the C/C++ configuration you use to launch your application, and in the "Main" tab verify the "C/C++ Application" path name)