# How to enable qt4 code completion in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt4

I develop app with some elements of Qt. I use cmake as build system and Eclipse only as editor and debugger. Everything comiles fine (thanks to CMake), however I can't force IDE to complete my Qt code.

Many times someone asked about it and the solution was to add include path. I did it of course, but

```
#include <QtSql>
```

is different, because there is no such file in include dir. It probably would work if I include all necassary files by hand. Is there any way to make Eclipse understand that "QtSql" means all classes from this module?

Comment: you know that the Eclipse support for C/C++ development it's not even comparable with something like QT creator right ?

Comment: of course, but my project is multilanguage, and lots of plugins to eclipse make it comfortable to have everything in one place.

Comment: out of curiosity, what this plugins are about ?

Comment: html editor and python + django, I know that editing html in eclipse is a bit stupid, but creating django apps in eclipse is very productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install qt4 eclipse integration package. You can find instructions [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-eclipse/eclipse-integration-installation.html)

As the webpage says, the module package should live inside `eclipse/plugins`, untar the package and start eclipse just one time from the command-line:

```
eclipse -clean
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume that you already have set up other Qt modules like QtCore or QtGui in Eclipse, if not please see this posting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12670991/1611055

To also use the QSql submodule (without the eclipse Qt Plugin which is, IMHO, not maintained anymore) you need to add the following settings in "Project Properties => C/C++ General => Paths and Symbols":

On the "Includes" tab, for the GNU C++ language, add the following include paths:

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtSql
```

On the "Symbols" tab, for the GNU C++ language, add the following symbols with a value of "1":

```
QT_SQL_LIB
```

With these settings, the Eclipse C++ indexer also knows the QtSql classes.