# Using Qt with Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

How can I use Qt with Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition? The express edition doesn't allow addins, so I can't use the Qt plugin for VS. I haven't been able to find anything I can follow; most discussions about this center on building Qt for VS 2010, but now that there are precompiled libraries for it that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Download and install the Qt libraries from http://releases.qt-project.org/qt4/source/qt-win-opensource-4.8.3-vs2010.exe
- Setup your project using a qmake project file (.pro)
- On the command line, call `qmake` then `nmake`
- Using an IDE, either [QtCreator](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Developer-Tools/) or [Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670710/eclipse-integrate-with-qt/12670991) would work - both can be set up to use qmake as the build tool

In essence, you basically only need the compiler and the linker from VS Express to build Qt applications.

Comment: @StrangeQuirk No. The express edition does not allow plugins, and Qt integration is done by using a plugin.